# Mount-SPContentDB did not upgrade the DB

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

The Mount-SPContentDatabase cmd should upgrade the DB to the maximum schema version currently available for the farm.

But it did not upgrade the DB. The current schema version is `15.0.4569.1000`, while the maximum schema version is `15.0.4911.1000`.

Comment: did you use NoB2BSiteUpgrade  in your command.? can you please share the command you used.?

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan Is NoB2BSiteUpgrade available in Mount-SPContentDB cmdlet? , he should use Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content -NoB2BSiteUpgrade to update the Content DB schema

Comment: @M.Qassas, I can see that NoB2BSiteUpgrade is available in Mount-SPContentDatabase command, check this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx

Comment: You are right, let me edit my answer that it also will work and please add your answer :)

Comment: by the way, he can't mount an existing mounted database, so he should perform now upgrade cmdlet, or dismount then mount it again with NoB2BSiteUpgrade

Answer (score 0):

As @Karthik Jaganathan mentioned you should use `NoB2BSiteUpgrade` with your `Mount-SPContentDatabase` cmdlet, but in your case, you can't perform `Mount-SPContentDatabase`  on already mounted database, you should dismount it ([Dismount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607764.aspx))  back then mount it again.

Or simply use `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase` cmdlet to upgrades the existing content database schema as the following:

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content -NoB2BSiteUpgrade
```

For more details check [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: We will be installing the latest CU soon and run the config wizard. So it will be upgraded. But, Should we should necassarily user NoB2BSiteUpgrade parameter with Mount cmd to upgrade the db?

Comment: you have already mounted your DB without -NoB2BSiteUpgrade parameter, , right? So no need to dismount and mount it again to can use -NoB2BSiteUpgrade parameter, instead of that run Upgrade-SPContentDatabase with -NoB2BSiteUpgrade parameter to upgrades the existing content database schema. Please don't hesitate to tell us if you have further queries

Comment: no it's not necessary it's an optional parameter, and you are correct once you run config wizard.  it will be upgraded, but this for your case because you will install CU so you will need to run config wizard but in general, you don't need to run Config wizard to upgrade schema because it causes down time so you should use mount with -NoB2BSiteUpgrade parameter or use upgrade as i mentioned

Comment: The msdn article for Mount cmd describes as below. The default behavior of this cmdlet causes an upgrade of the schema of the database and initiates upgraded builds for all site collections within the specified content database if required. To prevent initiation of upgraded builds of site collections, use the NoB2BSiteUpgrade parameter. This cmdlet does not trigger version-to-version upgrade of any site collections.

Comment: What I understood there is two type of upgrade build-to-build upgrades of site collections and database schema upgrades, and this cmdlet **by default** perform both two type upgrade but in case you don't need build-to-build upgrades you should use NoB2BSiteUpgrade to upgrade scheme only! but this not makes sense , so you should you run *Upgrade-SPContentDatabase ContentDB -NoB2BSiteUpgrade * as I have mentioned in abover and check the result or wait until install CU and run config wizard to upgrade it. last question Are you sure  it's a content db not other database like search